# Tridion DXA CT not outputing multimedia component metadata fields

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-1.2

DXA CT not populating the Multimedia component's metadata fields in the CT output. It returns empty when I preview the component in CME.

Do I need to set link level (as in DD4T) in the CT apart from the default TBB's?
My CT Source is as below: If yes, what is the format in DXA?

```
        <CompoundTemplate xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.3/CompoundTemplate">
          <TemplateInvocation>
            <Template xlink:href="tcm:x-x-x" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Render Component Content" />
            <TemplateParameters></TemplateParameters>
          </TemplateInvocation>
          <TemplateInvocation>
            <Template xlink:href="tcm:x-x-x" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Default Component Template Finish Actions" />
            <TemplateParameters></TemplateParameters>
          </TemplateInvocation>
        </CompoundTemplate>
```

- **Below is my component structure:**

-articles (Component Link Field)

--Paragraph (Embedded Field)

----title (text field)

----image (multimedia link field)

---------alt_text (text)

---------common fields (embedded fields)

------------author (text field)

------------use (text field)

Comment: This should work OOTB. Can you provide a screenshot of your Component metadata and the rendered DD4T JSON?